# Moving data between tables on a specific condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. In table Order, I have a column named customer_name. I am going to create a column named customer_id and customer_name is going to be dropped.

Before I drop that column, we have to look at the table Customer. Customer has one column name that matches the customer_name from Order. I want to find the SQL syntax that will let me move the id from Customer into the customer_id in Order, on the condition that Order.customer_name = Customer.name.

I am trying to use postgresql and have to learn how to use that, but even using regular SQL I have not found the solution yet.

I have tried:

```
ALTER TABLE Order
SELECT INTO customer_id
id from Customer
WHERE Order.customer_name = Customer.name;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Order (customer_id)
SELECT id
FROM Customer
WHERE Order.customer_name = Customer.name;
```

I am getting a syntax error.

Is there another way I should write the condition? Or is it because of pgadmin and I need to write some other way?

Comment: Note:`ORDER` is a keyword in SQL ,and a very bad choice for a table name.

Comment: You probably want UPDATE, not INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders ADD customer_id INT;

UPDATE Orders
    SET customer_id = c.id
    FROM Customers c
    WHERE o.customer_name = c.name;
```

Note:  After doing this, you should check that all orders have a valid id.  Then you may need to clean up records afterwards where the names do not match.

Comment: and may be for customers with same name

Comment: @angel.bonev . . . If customers have the same name, the OP cannot assign the ids correctly.